# Powershell Command Output select fields and compare

Tags: powershell

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv csv1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv csv2.csv
$merged = Merge-Csv -InputObject $csv1,$csv2 -ID "Invoice Number"
$merged | Select "Invoice Date","Invoice Number", @{name="CSV1InvStat";Expression={$_."CSV1 Invoice Status" -Replace "Open", "Unpaid" -Replace "Closed","Paid"}}, "CSV2 Invoice Status", "Customer", "Invoice Amount", "Paid Amount", @{Name=Diff;Expression={ $_."Invoice Amount" - $_."Paid Amount" }} | Sort "Invoice Number" | Export-Csv -encoding utf8 merged.csv
```

The result I get looks like:

```
Invoice Date     Invoice Number     CSV1InvStat     CSV2 Invoice Status   CSV1Amount  ...
4/1/2016         INVPQ-0001         Paid            Unpaid                3,000.00
6/30/2016        HKXLY43901         Paid            Paid                  500
```

What I'm looking to do is compare the "CSV1InvStat" field with the "CSV2 Invoice Status" **after** doing the replacement:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv csv1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv csv2.csv
$merged = Merge-Csv -InputObject $csv1,$csv2 -ID "Invoice Number"
$merged | Select "Invoice Date","Invoice Number", @{name="CSV1InvStat";Expression={$_."CSV1 Invoice Status" -Replace "Open", "Unpaid" -Replace "Closed","Paid"}}, "CSV2 Invoice Status",@{Name=StatusDiff;Expression={IF($_."CSV1InvStat" -eq $_."CSV2 Invoice Status") {0} Else {1}}}, "Customer", "Invoice Amount", "Paid Amount", @{Name=Diff;Expression={ $_."Invoice Amount" - $_."Paid Amount" }} | Sort "Invoice Number" | Export-Csv -encoding utf8 merged.csv
```

The problem is with:

```
@{Name="StatusDiff";Expression={IF($_."CSV1InvStat" -eq $_."CSV2 Invoice Status") {0} Else {1}}}
```

Which I thought would give me a column in merged.csv after the statuses with a 1 if the status are different, and a 0 if they're the same.  It doesn't seem to work though, I just get a 0 whether they match or not.  I think this is because CSV1InvStat doesn't technically exist in the data.

Is there a way to do this, or am I just better off having the users memorize an excel formula (=IF(C2=D2,0,1)) and doing this manually?

Comment: Can you edit and provide the full command(s) you're trying to use for the part you're having problems with?

Comment: As-is my guess is that it's because you're trying to do it in a single Select-Object, so the CSV1InvStat calculated property hasn't been processed/created/brought into scope at the time the IF is performed. If you break it down into two separate select-object statements (one that creates  CSV1InvStat, and then a second one that uses the already processed CSV1InvStat to create StatusDiff) does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I just wonder if there's a more elegant way to do that.

Comment: A more elegant way of doing this would be to import the spreadsheet as an array of objects (import-csv).  Then loop through the objects and evaluate your expressions, saving the data back into the objects.  You can replace the existing properties or add new ones as you desire.  Then, once you've got everything in place, export the array into a CSV.  The nature of this sort of nested piping is that it is difficult to read.  My point is that an actual script with loops would be more elegant, easier to document and to read AND to maintain.